# Android Auto Template quota limit (Template flow restrictions violated)

Tags: android, android-auto

Is thre any way to brake `androidx.car.app.model.Template` limit in `Screen`'s `onGetTemplate()`?

***Stacktrace:***

```
2022-01-27 13:26:10.862 22269-22283/? E/CarApp.H.Tem: Error: [app: ComponentInfo{com.cloudmade.android.cbuddy/com.cloudmade.android.cbuddy.androidauto.service.CarService}, type: null, cause: axo: Unsupported template type as the last step in a task. [template: ListTemplate, ID: 69f3b46c-090d-4fb8-8c6c-fd3656dea475], debug msg: Template flow restrictions violated]
    axo: Unsupported template type as the last step in a task. [template: ListTemplate, ID: 69f3b46c-090d-4fb8-8c6c-fd3656dea475]
        at azt.onSuccess(SourceFile:50)
        at androidx.car.app.IOnDoneCallback$Stub.onTransact(SourceFile:10)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)
```